# @Transactional and inherited methods

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm working with two databases (MySQL and HSQL), so I need two transaction managers in my Spring app. Please have a look at this code:

```
public abstract class ClientService implements IClientService{
public void doSomething(){
}
}

public interface IClientService{
void doSomething();
}

@Transactional("txManagerHSQL")
public class ClientServiceHSQL extends ClientService{
}

@Transactional("txManagerMySQL")
public class ClientServiceMySQL extends ClientService{
}
```

I want `ClientServiceHSQL` and `ClientServiceMySQL` to perform `doSomething()` on different databases, but I'm getting `"org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread"` exception. It seems that `@Transactional` annotation doesn't affect inherited methods. At this time I have to implement `doSomething()` in each `@Transactional` class to be able to call `doSomething()` with success, but for me this is not nice. Is there any way to make inherited methods also transactional?

Comment: In such case, I think it is more appropriate to control transaction on spring app context config instead of using @Transactional annotation.

Comment: Do you mean declaring <tx:advice> ? I totally got rid of all xml files, I did everything in annotations so now I don't know how to do what you suggested.

Comment: I just think, by design, it is inappropriate to have 2 child class because you want them involve in different transaction.  It should be simply 2 instance of same service class.  By the way, apart from having XML based configuration, you still have Java based Spring configuration, I am not sure if it will work for you http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java .  However I do recommend you not to get rid of all xml.  You can use annotations for most case, but in some rare-case you still need explicit configurations

Comment: sho wwhere you transactionmanagers are defined, this looks fine